# Missing reference using Brother Label Solutions SDK

Tags: microsoft-excel, printer

I have written an excel add-in in VBA that takes a formatted list of addresses and communicates with my Brother QL-570 label printer using the Brother “Label Solutions” SDK: http://www.brother.com/product/dev/label/bpac/download/bpaccci156/index.htm

I have previously run this code on another computer where the SDK is installed and it works perfectly. Now using it on my machine it is not working. My machine runs Windows 10 and I have Excel 2010. Upon running the add-in I get this error:
*“Runtime Error 249, ActiveX can’t create object.”*

From my understanding this error indicates a missing file. However from looking under Tools -> References within Developer I can see *“Brother b-PAC 3.1 Type Library”* is checked following successful installation. As such I am not sure what the issue is.

Lastly, I do not believe the code is the issue as this works on another PC, regardless find the sub’s code below for reference.

What are potential causes of this error?

MY CODE:

The error is occurring at the fifth line: “Set objDoc = CreateObject(“bpac.Document””).

```
Public Sub PrintLabels(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)

Dim numRows As Integer

numRows = GetRowCount(2)

Dim objDoc As bpac.Document
Set objDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")

For i = 1 To numRows
    Dim templateFile As String
    Dim mailService As String
    mailService = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 11).Text
    If mailService = "1" Then
        templateFile = labelTemplateFile1st
    ElseIf mailService = "2" Then
        templateFile = labelTemplateFile2nd
    Else
        templateFile = labelTemplateFile
    End If
    If objDoc.Open(templateFile) Then
        Dim printers() As Variant
        printers = objDoc.Printer.GetInstalledPrinters()

        Dim installedPrinterName As Variant
        installedPrinterName = printers(0)

        objDoc.SetPrinter printers(0), True
        objDoc.StartPrint "Label", bpoDefault 'Sets label cutting to default value.

        objDoc.GetObject("ORDERNUM").Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Text
        objDoc.GetObject("NAMDRESS").Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).Text
        objDoc.GetObject("ORDERDETS").Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3).Text

        objDoc.PrintOut 1, bpoDefault
        objDoc.EndPrint

        objDoc.Close
    Else
        MsgBox objDoc.ErrorCode
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The SDK on the new system may have installed differently to accommodate an upgraded OS. Have you tried removing the reference, save, close, open, add it again?

Comment: I have tried now, same result sadly.

Comment: I found this site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828550/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications . Start at "examine the automation server". Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this is an old post, it was my first result when googling this issue.

I found that it was related to my 32bit version of Microsoft Office, that I am running on a 64 operating system.

I installed the 32bit version of the BPac SDK in addition to the 64bit version to solve my problem. (I did not test uninstalling the 64bit version first)